# Bootstrap Can't Achieve Proper Spacing Between Navbar and Page Content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the problem:
[image]

And here's the code. Most of it has been copy and pasted from examples.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">

<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
<li class="hidden">
  <a href="#page-top"></a>
</li>
<li class="page-scroll">
  <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="page-scroll active">
  <a href="/downloads.html">Downloads</a>
</li>
<li class="page-scroll">
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container">
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</div>
```

I'm currently using a custom Bootstrap theme (https://bootswatch.com/yeti/), and have linked up the custom Bootstrap CSS, and regular Bootstrap Javascript and jQuery correctly via CDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source for the [fixed navbar example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/), you'll see that they add padding to the top of the body to account for the navbar:

```
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

That rule pushes the body content down enough to clear the navbar.